# Multiple UIViewControllers simultaneously

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I would like to have a UITableView in a navigation controller occupying the entire screen.  I have a smaller custom UIView which needs to slide up from the bottom, squeezing the table view by 100 pixels.  The custom view needs to be static, not moving while the user navigates the tableview.  Ive been told not to have 2 UIViewControllers (VC) managing views on the same screen.

Currently, my AppDelegate adds a subview to its window from a VC, which then loads the tableview and custom view with

[self addSubview:tablviewcontroller.view];
[self addSubview:customViewController.view];

How should this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

the way I would structure this is as follows:
have a UIViewController subclass whose view takes up the entire screen. It will have two subviews.
First subview: The view of the UINavigationController that contains your table view controller.
Second subview: the custom UIView.

Have the UINavigationController's frame initially be set to the entire bounds of the main view controller's view and the custom view's frame just below the visible area of the screen.

When you need to slide up the view, use UIView animation to animate changing the frame of the UINavigationController's view by decreasing the height and change the frame of the custom UIView by changing its y coordinate to now be in-frame.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. You want a navigation controller, of which the root view is a table view. Then, possible by an user input, you want this table view to slide up by 100 pixels, and another view takes place at the bottom. While the other view stays there, the user may keep using the table view.

Here is how I would do it:

Create a generic view controller (let's call it `NavigationWithAuxiliaryViewController`). The root view of this class covers all your application window.

This view has an instance of `UINavigationController`as its property, say `navController`. It also has an UIView (for the other view) as its property (say, `auxView`). Position the other view at the bottom. However, this view is hidden by default. Also, the frame of the root view of UINavigationController covers the entire view.

When you decide to squeeze up the table view, modify `frame` property of UINavigationController. Do something like this (not this ugly though):

```
if (slideViewOn) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"slideUp" context:nil];
    navController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 260);
    auxView.hidden = NO;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
} else {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"slideDown" context:nil];
    navController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    auxView.hidden = YES;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

The easiest way to squeeze up the whole navigation/table stuff is to modify the whole frame for the navigation controller, which is why you need a separate view (out of the navigation controller) for the other view.